# iOS 6 breaks GeoLocation in webapps (apple-mobile-web-app-capable)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, geolocation, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have an app that does a simple textbook navigator.geoLocation.watchPosition(...) that works great in iOS 5.x both in Safari and as a web app (using apple-mobile-web-app-capable meta tag).

However, in iOS6, GeoLocation does not work in the webapp.  It still works in safari as expected, but when I run the webapp, it prompts me for location permission, then silently fails.  I see the location icon, but no events are thrown from watchLocation.  I get no error events or any location events.

Has anyone run into this?  Any workarounds?  It's definitely iOS6 specific and also specific to the apple-mobile-web-app-capable/webapp.

Comment: Just updated to iOS 6.1.1 and this still appears to be an issue.

Answer (score 14):

This is definitely a bug but I found a work around. You aren't going to like this but at least it will get your web app working again. You need to examine the User Agent header and if it contains "iPhone OS 6" then do not use:

```
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />
```

Yes, this means that it won't be a true web app and you will get the Safari header and footer bars. But at least it will make your app work again from the home screen. You can see how this works by going to my site [www.nextbus.com](http://www.nextbus.com).

Note that it appears that Google ran into this problem. Try going to `maps.google.com` and then adding the web app to your homescreen. The geolocation will work for it but you will indeed see the ugly Safari header and footer bars.

Please complain loudly to Apple!

Comment: Yeah - that's what I did for now - I just removed the apple-mobile-web-app-capable meta tag so although geolocation now works, I don't get the visual benefits of a true iOS chromeless web app. I suspect many others will stumble on this in the next few days. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: The good news is that if an end user saves the app to the home screen, it'll still behave like a home screen app.

Answer (score 3):

The good news is: I've done it... I've figured it out. The bad news is: somebody smarter than me is going to have to tell you why this works, whereas any other variation of this solution or any of the other solutions offered don't work. This was a hard-fought victory but I'm too embarrassed to say how many hours (days) it took me to figure this out. Without further ado:

```
if (window.navigator.geolocation) {

            var accuracyThreshold = 100,
            timeout = 10 * 1000,
            watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
                $('#latitude').val(position.coords.latitude); // set your latitude value here
                $('#longitude').val(position.coords.longitude); // set your longitude value here

                // if the returned distance accuracy is less than your pre-defined accuracy threshold,
                // then clear the timeout below and also clear the watchPosition to prevent it from running continuously
                position.coords.accuracy < accuracyThreshold && (clearTimeout(delayClear), navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID))
            }, function(error) {

                // if it fails to get the return object (position), clear the timeout
                // and cancel the watchPosition() to prevent it from running continuously
                clearTimeout(delayClear);

                navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);

                // make the error message more human-readable friendly
                var errMsg;

                switch (error.code) {
                    case '0':
                        errMsg = 'Unknown Error';
                        break;
                    case '1':
                        errMsg = 'Location permission denied by user.';
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        errMsg = 'Position is not available';
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        errMsg = 'Request timeout';
                        break;
                }
            }, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: timeout,
                maximumAge: 0
            }),
            delayClear = setTimeout(function() {
                navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
            }, timeout + 1E3); // make this setTimeout delay one second longer than your watchPosition() timeout
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("Geolocation is not supported.");
        }
```

Note: for some reason, this doesn't seem to work as consistently if the execution of this code it delayed at some point after initially launching the app. So, this is the FIRST thing I execute in my initialization method.

Note: The only other thing I've added to my app is, when I need to use the geolocation data (which, for me, takes place after the initialization of several other Classes/Object Literals), is to check for the latitude/longitude values. If they exist, continue; If not, run the above geolocation method again, then continue.

Note: One of the things that threw me for a long time was that I only needed to get the current position of the user. I didn't need to track the users' movements. I kept trying different iterations of this with the getCurrentPosition() method. For whatever reason, it doesn't work. So, this is the solution I came up with. Run it like you're going to track the users location (to get their location in the first place), then once you've gotten their location, clear the watchPosition ID to prevent it from tracking them. If you need to track their location as it changes over time, you can of course... not clear the watchPosition ID.

HTH. From everything I've been reading, there are a lot of developers who need this functionality to work for their mission-critical apps. If this solution doesn't work for you, I'm not sure what other direction I can give. Having said that, I've tested this several hundred times and this successfully retrieves the users' location in a WebApp (navigator.standalone) on iOS 6.

Comment: this is superb!  seeing as ioS 6.1 is still buggy with geolocation has anyone got an example of the above for running in watchPosition mode?

Answer (score 2):

here is a video of me replicating the bug and demonstrating a work around. This bug appears to exist weather you use the web app meta tag or not.

http://youtu.be/ygprgHh6LxA

Update: 121212 - IOS 6.1 Beta 3 testing shows the bug is still not resolved...

Update: 122012 - IOS 6.1 Beta 4 testing shows the bug is still not resolved...

---

**Update: 031113 - Replication Example**

Okay, it is a simple issue to replicate in just a few seconds. I feel it is not a safari, but an IOS issue. It’s almost as if Google wrote the bios for the IOS to meet the WC3 html geo location spec and took it with them when IOS6 kicked them off the bus.
Using an IOS device go here:

http://uc.myaesc.com/geoloctestorig.htm

Click start, watch should return result almost every second.
Then click the Google link to leave this page.
Then user browser back button to return
Click start.
Watch will return 1 to 3 records and hang.
Minimize safari (home button) and then restore (safari icon); stops hanging

That's it. until it does not hang, the issue remains.

Mark

UPDATE:

IOS 7.1 fixed the issue...

Comment: Link appears to be broken

Answer (score 1):

It appears it only works once, then any secondary calls fail. One alternative is to cache the result and use the cached result if you have one, though this means you can't have an app that follows someone's position.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer as it seems like Home Screen apps in ios6 has some bug related to GeoLocation, but I found the following link very helpful. It explains that as Home Screen apps are now stored like native apps, they have their own storage/caching.

Geolocation  works on the first iteration but fails to update from then on. the work around is to remove the following meta tag so that Home Screens app run in Browser mode (I am not sure if it is exactly call a Browser mode). The app will unfortunately render with the browser headers and footers, but GeoLocationwill be working again.

`<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />`

[iOS 6 Geolocation and Local Data Storage](http://www.elevatedgis.com/blog/2012/09/21/ios-6-geolocation-and-local-data-storage/)

> "Data in Home Screen apps are now stored like native apps.  Native apps each have their own sandbox where their data is stored, backed up and restored to.  Prior to iOS 6, Home Screen apps shared data with the same app running in the browser.  If the user cleared the cache in the browser, the Home Screen version of the app would lose its data too.With iOS 6, Home Screen apps’ data gets saved to a sandbox just like native apps.  Backups and restores handle the data properly, and clear cache in the browser will not affect them."

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Looks like watchPosition is simply failing out after the first position is received. I haven't found a work around yet, but I wanted to confirm that I was experiencing issues.

Using these samples:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

I get expected results on ios5 but ios6 drops the ball with watchPosition.

Comment: I'm raising the issue in the apple dev forum to see if anyone has any good info.

Comment: I just visited the above url from my device.  It's running iOS 6 and when I clicked on "Try It" it displays a map.  Was it suppose to do something else?

Comment: Try the one under Geolocation object - Other interesting Methods - and go walk around... what you should see is the position coords changing slightly as you move around.

Comment: It appears as though it may be related javascript callbacks. 

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/373086936093025?browse=search_5009002cb69058a73627413

There is a success callback for watchPosition. Still poking around.

Comment: When you walk around it continuously changes the lat/lon?

Comment: @Morgan Yes, I followed the same steps and see it change after moving around on iOS 6 with an iPhone 4S.  I did notice one thing that you may want to check: I had to go into Settings -> Privacy -> Location and explicitly allow Safari for Location Services.  It may be the case that Apple turned this off by default with the iOS 6 update.

Comment: @wulong that is bizarre. I double checked location prefs, and safari is allowed. ios6-4s I get an initial lat/lon but it doesn't update. If I exit safari, then re-open it, it jogs through a couple of points as it changes accuracy but then it sits idle with no change again. Perhaps there is some caching going on...

Comment: The issue I raised above is specific to webapps (html apps with the apple-mobile-web-app-capable meta).  GeoLocation is working fine in Safari browser on iOS -- it's only when you save the app to the home screen with the attribute above that makes it run as a full-screen, chromeless app does it fail.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm I get the same problem when running my web app in fullscreen.

Interestingly, when Safari in Fullscreen asked permission to use my location, the website title was 'web' rather than the title of the website, as in previous versions of iOS.

Removing the "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" meta tag is fine, and it works, but only if you "Add to Homescreen" again. We have ~7000 daily users who have already added our icon to their homescreen. Getting them to do so again, then potentially again when a fix is implimented isn't great.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed under iOS 6.1!  It wasn't in the recent betas, but today's final 6.1 release seems to be good with my testing.

Comment: Ok - it's not 100% fixed.  I am getting an initial location event which was not happening prior to 6.1, but I'm not getting subsequent events from watchlocation.  I'm only getting the first one.  I'll work on alternative solutions and get back to this thread shortly (I'm the original poster)

Comment: With iOS 6.1 on my iPhone 4s it I can get watchPosition reliably only if Wi-Fi is turned off when I start my web app.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be fixed in iOS 6.1, finally! See my site www.slople.com where it works again under 6.1

Answer (score 0):

This is FINALLY fixed in iOS7 beta (beta 2 is all I've tested)!

Answer (score 0):

You must take care of non secure content loaded. For me loading all javascript, images and css from secure context solved the problem with safari.