# HTML5 geolocation accuracy Android vs iOs are very different

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, geolocation

I noticed difference between the HTC android and iPhone 4S. I tested the same html5 script with watchLocation and the accuracy on the HTC stays in 3 meters while the iPhone begins with 5 meters and after 1 minute or so it climbs to 100 till 1000 meters and never come back closer.

I use the html5 code in webView in the apps.

Does someone know why?

The code:

```
trackId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, null, {maximumAge:0, timeout:60000, enableHighAccuracy:true});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, after spending hours, almost days, I found this:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4313850?start=0&tstart=0

[iOS 6 breaks GeoLocation in webapps (apple-mobile-web-app-capable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503815/ios-6-breaks-geolocation-in-webapps-apple-mobile-web-app-capable/14410106#14410106)

So, thanks Apple!